# triggers for multiple tables in one delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a BEFORE DELETE trigger on every table. It copies the record in a log table. Works fine if I have one table in my DELETE statement. But when I do a DELETE like this:

```
DELETE t1, t2 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.id = some_id
```

It just triggers the BEFORE DELETE on table1 and not on table2. The record on table2 is deleted. The JOIN works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your table definitions -- [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

if I get you right, You can do this automatically by considering the **foreign keys** as you can set the **ON DELETE** action to be **Cascade**